# Mysteriously not encountering compiler error

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, compiler-errors, clang

https://godbolt.org/z/aexGW1x48

In the above code, in the following line

`std::int64_t tempVal = std::ceil(tempVal);`

`tempVal` is referenced in `std::ceil` before it is declared or instantiated. Yet, the code compiles just fine. How come compiler does not throw an error? Is it a compiler bug?

I tried clang/msvc/gcc and it seems like msvc does throw compiler error, but clang/gcc both passes.
You might write that kinda of code - yes, no one probably. But I had a typo and it was not  caught by gcc :(

Comment: It seems even `-Wall -Wextra` does not pick this up. I would expect a warning about the variable being uninitialized.

Comment: "_before it is declared or instantiated_": No, `tempVal` is declared and visible to name lookup immediately before the `=`. The line has undefined behavior when evaluated because it accesses `tempVal` before its lifetime starts, but as long as it is isn't evaluated, the program is well-formed and a standard-conforming compiler must compile it. (A warning from the compiler would however be allowed and desirable.)

Comment: When I asked this question, the answer I got was that this is allowed in the language, and code like `int i = i;` could be used to indicate explicitly an intentionally uninitialized variable.  The usage in the OP code snippet would be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Eljay `int i = i;` is also UB because it accesses an indeterminate value. If at all it was only allowed for `unsigned char`/`std::byte`, but with C++20 the rules were changed so that it is UB for those as well (because lifetime starts only after the initialization).

Comment: @user17732522 • That's what I would have thought as well.  But the person who suggested it was Bjarne Stroustrup, to Sean Parent.  (However, this was before C++20.)  And it only works (if at all) for primitive types.

Comment: @Eljay Can't really argue with that and I don't doubt that it has been used like that. But I don't think there was ever any special case in the rules so that `T x = x;` doesn't incur a read and write of `x`. But even if not optimized by the compiler and naively translated to a load and store, it will work on usual architectures for most types. But it was only guaranteed for `unsigned char`/`std::byte` because the uninitialized memory loaded from `x` could be a trap representation in general. For example it could load a signalling NaN in case of `float`/`double`/`long double`.

Comment: @user17732522 • Bjarne was off-the-cuff spitballing, and perhaps not thought every ramification.  In comparison, **D** programming language would represent it like `int i = void;`, whereas in **D** `int i;` gets default initialized to `0`.